# Spawn mongodump cluster in nodeJs exit code 1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodump

I want to run mongodump to a cluster in Mongo Atlas. I have copied the code to do this from Mongo Atlas.

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://lims:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.f3zyz.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>
```

If I replace "PASSWORD" and "DATABASE" and run the command on the console it works as expected.

But when I try to run it from Nodejs as a childprocess it exits with code 1.

```
const backupProcess = spawn('mongodump', 
        [
            '--uri mongodb+srv://lims:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.f3zyz.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>',
        ] 
       );
```

Why it works in the console but not in Node?

Is there a way to see what is happening in the childProcees? I have tried listening to `backupProcess.on('message', (msg)=> console.log(msg))` but nothing is logged.

Answer (score 2):

args is an array of string arguments. You put all of the arguments into a single argument. Try:

```
const backupProcess = spawn('mongodump', 
        [
            '--uri', 'mongodb+srv://lims:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.f3zyz.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>',
        ] 
       );
```

To see process output, set [stdio options](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) to 'inherit',

Answer (score 0):

You can put the argument with an equal sign,

```
const backupProcess = spawn('mongodump', 
  [
    '--uri=mongodb+srv://lims:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.f3zyz.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>'
  ] 
);
```